# Using GeoTools: What is the Latitude and Longitude in com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate class?

Tags: java, coordinate, geotools

I will use `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate` as my coordinate class.
But don't find any document which is the correct order of the coordinate. is it standard?

Here's the java doc link -> http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Coordinate.html

My question is:
What is x? (is it Latitude or Longitude?)
What is y? (is it Latitude or Longitude?)

Any guidance is appreciated.

**UPDATES1**
Let me to add this. I am using **GeoTools** Java Library. Then, the library is using that Coordinate class. **How does GeoTools treat the Coordinate.x and Coordinate.y?**

Comment: From its javadoc: "A lightweight class used to store coordinates on the 2-dimensional Cartesian plane". So you have a point in the geometrical sense not in the geographical one. So it depends on you how you want to view it (although it's common to see x as the longitude and y as the latitutde).

Comment: That class doesn't seem to have anything to do with latitude and longitude, it's just a geometric abstraction.

Comment: You are both correct. I have updated my post. How does GeoTools treat Coordinate.x and Coordinate.y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the projection you are using. Check the EPSG definition and it will list the axis order. For example see http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/prettywkt/. If you are using GeoTools then you probably don't need to be worrying about the JTS internals.

**UPDATE**

I remembered this document which may help (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html)

Comment: yes you are right. but I just need to know what is x,y in geotools. if it depends on the projection, I really don't know about projection but I am working with ESRI Shape File then read it using GeoTools. I will accept this as the best answer as it provides example of clear definition of X(EAST),Y(NORTH).

Comment: No you missunderstand my point - there are many projections that define X(North) Y (East) so you have to work out which you are using by querying the CRS object with your datastore.

Answer (score 2):

In Cartesian coordinates, x maps left-right and y maps up-down.  So, a natural fit oriented in front of a map would be to use x for longitude (east-west) and y for latitude (north-south).  There's a z as well, that could be used for altitude.

Comment: You are correct. But I need confirmation on how it treats using GeoTools Library.

Comment: From their docs, it appears they support quite a number of different formats.  You get to pick your favorite.  http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/opengis/cs.html

Comment: I found this statement -> `The formulae for these map projections can be used to convert (latitude, longitude) coordinates from a geographic CRS to planar (x,y) coordinates in a projected CRS.`. What does it mean (Coordinate.x is latitude, Coordinate.y is longitude)?